# How to call Spark2-submit command from Python script/code

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Spark with no knowledge. I was asked to look into existing program and was given following task
1) file1.py
2) file2.py
version is Spark2.0
In file1.py --> Spark is initiated using SparkSession.
Basically, I have to call file2.py from file1.py. How can I do that?

in Console, I can run these individual files like:
Spark2-Submit file1.py
Spark2-Submit file2.py
runs fine. But programmatically, how to call file2.py from file1.py.

Comment: Why you want to call one pyspark job from another pyspark job, any reason for it? my suggestion you can write wrapper python or shell script to call one after another.

Comment: job 2 is dependent on job 1. so, as soon as job 1 is done we want to trigger(automate) job 2

Comment: If you want to set the dependency like when first Spark Job is successful then you can start second, this can be achieved using shell no need to call second spark job from first spark job. Below is shell approach you can look for same.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dependency in shell job like this, though I have not ran script but logically work like this. Hope this will be helpful.

```
#./bin/sh

echo "Spark Job started ..."

echo "First Spark script-1 started ..."

spark2-Submit file1.py

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "First Spark script-1 ran successfully..."
    echo "Second Spark script-2 started ..."
    spark2-Submit file2.py
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
       echo "Second Spark script-2 ran successfully..."
    else 
       echo "Second Spark script-2 failed ..."
       exit 1
else
    echo "First Spark script-1 failed ..."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: @Ajay- this work awesome. The challange is Job1 --> does multiple sub-task so as soon as task 1 is done, we want to run the Job2 for that particular task and so on. Instead of letting all subtask done we want to call Job 2 for each subtask inside Job1.
    ` for loop i in subtask_list
     call Job2 for i
    `
i was told to call Job2 using Structured Streamline. Since I am .Net developer It takes lot of effort to figure out thing.

Comment: Jay- Spark is data centric language and it runs in distributed manner, code runs on each worker node in cluster. Basically you cannot setup workflow using Spark. Either you have to do it workflow specific tools like in hadoop oozie is there, where you can orchestrate your workflow as you required. But call another spark job from other job is not good idea.